# How to grab part of URL using bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Currently I have this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:currentUrl=document.location.href;document.location.assign(currentUrl+'embed');
```

What this does is that it grabs the current URL
`www.example.com/knZg_INW8fL/`
and adds
`embed`
behind it so it can be embeded

However, sometimes, the URL will have a
`?hl=en`
behind it. How can I remove that and simultaneously add
`embed`
behind it?

Comment: It is. What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I am so sorry, I realize that I didn't explain my question properly and have edited it. @esqew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the random chars will not have `?` because it is a special character. the easiest way is to split the string on `?` and take the first part!

If you also want to remove the last '/' from the string, you can slice it off

```
javascript:document.location.assign(document.location.href.split('?')[0].slice(0,-1));
```

```js
console.log('www.example.com/knZg_INW8fL/?hl=en'.split('?')[0].slice(0,-1));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for... And so sorry for the confusing question earlier on. Thumbs up to you for understanding my question even though it was so confusing